# Clear button that clears checkboxes using CSS

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to create a clear button that clears the checkboxes using only CSS and HTML? Reason being is because the clear function DOES NOT work with IE8, therefore CSS and HTML is the ONLY way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with:

```
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
```

See a live example:

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="yes" /> Option 1<br />
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```